# Saving Zip Files Using URLs

Tags: html, href

I am trying to download a series of files using a Python script. When I click on the link on the website, I can download it without any trouble. However whenever I paste the URL from the link into my browser (ie: example.com/file.zip), I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Here is what the link looks like:

```
<a class="a-dl dl-file dl-zip zip" href="http://www.truefx.com/dev/data/2016/JUNE-2016/AUDJPY-2016-06.zip" download="AUDJPY-2016-06.zip">AUDJPY-2016-06.zip</a>
```

Any ideas on what the problem is and how I can work around/fix it?

Comment: it is downloading but it is failed and it is a partial download not complete from website---  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLJQJd

Comment: Need more information: specifically, more details around the 400 bad -reqeust error message

Comment: problem is with the zip file, updated codepen with zip file download ..check it once - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLJQJd

Comment: Maybe the href is being dynamically modified in the website page via jQuery.